# Get hospitals with Foursquare

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to get a list of hospitals near GPS coordinates. According to this link

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/resources/categories

The category ID for hospital is "4bf58dd8d48988d196941735"

I was reading the documentation and found this working example

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=29.253219,-81.732377&client_id=MYCLIENTID&client_secret=MYCLIENTSECRET&limit=1&v=20180628

Then I modified it to get the hospitals only

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4bf58dd8d48988d196941735?ll=29.253219,-81.732377&client_id=MYCLIENTID&client_secret=MYCLIENTSECRET&limit=1&v=20180628

But it returns the following result

```
{"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"param_error","errorDetail":"Value 4bf58dd8d48988d196941735 is invalid for venue id","requestId":"5b5c04226a60714256a11fff"},"response":{}}
```

Any idea where my mistake is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `categoryId` parameter.

e.g.

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=29.253219,-81.732377&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d196941735&client_id=MYCLIENTID&client_secret=MYCLIENTSECRET&limit=1&v=20180628